# Linking against a shared library with setuid

Tags: ubuntu, linker, shared-libraries, ld, ldd

I want to link against a shared library which has its owner changed to root and setuid is set:

```
$ ls -la
total 3616
drwxrwxr-x 2 chiron chiron    4096 Mai 29 21:59 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 chiron chiron    4096 Mai 29 23:16 ..
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root   chiron 3692440 Mai 29 21:59 chiron_lowlevel_controller_node
```

When I start the executable I get the following error:

```
$ ./chiron_lowlevel_controller_node
./chiron_lowlevel_controller_node: error while loading shared libraries: libxmlrpcpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This confuses me because ldd returns:

```
$ ldd chiron_lowlevel_controller_node | grep xml
libxmlrpcpp.so => /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so (0x00007effe8c86000)
```

And libxmlrpcpp.so does indeed exist:

```
$ ls -la | grep xml
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  122608 Mär 18 19:03 libxmlrpcpp.so
```

I also know that libxmlrpcpp.so is not corrupted or so, because when I remove the setuid and change the owner to chiron, the error does not occur.

**Extra question:**

```
$ readelf -d chiron_lowlevel_controller
```

returns many directories in the RUNPATH:

```
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [Many:Directories:Separated:By:Double:Dots]
```

But if I move libxmlrpcpp.so in one of those directories,

```
$ ldd chiron_lowlevel_controller_node | grep xml
libxmlrpcpp.so => not found
```

This [article](https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2016/09/17/shared-libraries/#rpath-and-runpath) claims that ldd searches in all directories of runpath for a shared library, so why does it not work when I move the shared library? Or is that article wrong?

**System information:**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: I noticed that when I keep the owner as chiron and do not set suid bit and then do sudo su, then it also fails to find libxmlrpcpp.so. What is even more interesting is that using LD_DEBUG I found that the dynamic loader does not search in any of the RUNPATH directories.

Comment: To clarify: ld does not search in the RUNPATH directories if I sudo su first.